# Selecting records based on date from MySQL

Tags: mysql, web-services, hibernate, named-query

I have two columns in my table say Id, date. date is date timestamp (eg:2014-04-01 02:30:00).

I want to return all the records based on the date (2014-04-01) instead of giving entire time stamp. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about index, use the following:

```
select Id from table where DATE(date) = '2014-04-01'
```

otherwise

```
select Id from table where date between '2014-04-01 00:00:00' and '2014-04-01 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT p
FROM Customer p
WHERE code =?1
  AND DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y%m%d') BETWEEN "2014-04-01" AND "2014-04-30"
```

Comment: I have used this query for selecting records with in date range like start and end dates.@NamedQuery(name="Customer.CustomerLoyalityByCodeAndTime", query = "SELECT p FROM Customer p WHERE code =?1 AND time BETWEEN ?2 AND ?3")  In the same way i want to have all the records with same date irrespective of the time. I want to input only date not time

Answer (score 0):

**Try Thiz**

```
select id from table where DATE(date)='2014-04-01';
```